# callback in rules of spider doesn;t work

Tags: callback, scrapy

I crawl  a website called zhihu using scrapy, but the callback in rules is not called. The log showed Closing spider after showing  DEBUG: Crawled (200). I wonder why the spider doesn't work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post what's in the image as text. And consider adding some more details.

Comment: There are no links on that page which point to `https://www.zhihu.com/topic/.*`. There are links to `https://www.zhihu.com/question/.*`. So that is why it is not working for you